# echo char(128) and above from php does not work

Tags: javascript, php, utf-8, echo, chr

I have a server side process.php script that echos two chars:

```
echo chr(127);
echo chr(128);
```

On the client side, I have a java script (running in an html page with UTF-8 encoding) that posts to the php script and expects a response:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// post xhr to php, check for DONE and 200, and get the response
console.log(xhr.responseText);
```

For 127, I get the response as a string with one character representing 127 as expected.
But for 128 and above it gives me 3 chars, -17, -65 -67. Combed and trawled the net, but nothing. Am quite surprised to not find any info online on transmitting bytes from a server to a client. Am a desktop C++ programmer, btw hence this has me stumped!

Comment: What character set are you using. What encoding are your pages in?

Comment: How and where exactly are you determining what chars it gives you?

Comment: IIRC `chr(128)` and above are considered "non-printable" characters in PHP

Comment: <<What character set are you using. What encoding are your pages in? >> 
I suppose it is utf-8, which is specified in the head section of my html (nowhere else).

Comment: <<How and where exactly are you determining what chars it gives you?>>
I pass the resultant response to a C++ function written in emscripten. In that function its easy - parse the response char by char and print out the typecasted integer value.

Comment: <<IIRC chr(128) and above are considered "non-printable" characters in PHP>> Does that mean its technically impossible to have a string passed from a php server to a javascript function that contains these >= 128 chars? In that case, this is a futile exercise?

Comment: The single byte value 128 simply is not valid UTF-8 to begin with. (`echo chr(128);` into a page that _is_ proper UTF-8, will only get you a � replacement character shown.) It is very unclear what you are actually trying to _achieve_ here, so the only advice I have as of now, would be to not send arbitrary byte values as _text_. Find _some_ other format to transport whatever data you actually need to transport here.

Comment: @CBroe, I am trying to send int and float data from the server to the client. Initially, I sent it in a comma separated text format and parsed it on the client side. This works. Am trying to make it more efficient - one is to avoid the number to string conversion on server and two to avoid parsing commas and converting string to a number on the client. When I do this way between two C++ apps via cout (then reading the pipe), its blazingly fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are sending bytes, you need to stop thinking about text and characters. JavaScript is UTF-16 internally, and you'll be transporting text across HTTP from PHP which gets to set it's own encoding.

If you want to parse [raw bytes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Handling_binary_data) in JavaScript, you'll want to look into the [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer). Once you receive your data, you can compose a [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) over it and grab the bytes. If you are 8-bit only, you shouldn't need to worry about endianness, either.

```js
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr
            .addEventListener(
                'load',
                () => {
                    const buffer = xhr.response;
                    const view = new DataView( buffer );
                    const byte = view.getUint8( 0 );
                    console.dir( byte );
                }
            );
        xhr.open( 'GET', '/my/end-point' );
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.send();
```

Comment: Chris, this looks promising. Its late night here now, so I am gonna try out this first thing tomorrow morning! Thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks, Chris.